# Signalr negotiate returns 200 and 404 alternatively

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am facing a strange issue where SignalR negotiate requests suddenly started returning 404 on first call and then returns 200. So the connection never succeeds. The Hub is hosted in an ASP.NET web application and Owin is started using the Startup class decorated with the OwinStartupAttribute. The bin folder has Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb but the Configuration method in the Startup class never gets called. I know it's not called because the default.aspx page was visible in browser even when Startup.Configuration method had a `throw new NotImplementedException().` I updated all SignalR and Ownin references to the latest but issue remains the same.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying to figure out the problem it turned out to be an issue with the server configuration. SignalR worked fine when the application was installed on a virtual machine on a different host. We haven't been able to determine the exact cause of the issue, but I would consider this question as closed.